# issue creating systemd unit file

Tags: systemd

I am trying to create a systemd unit file to replace the command

```
RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rails resque:start_workers[2]
```

So that the workers can start when he machine boots.
The file I have created is:

```
[Unit]
Description=background workers
After=httpd.service solr.service

[Service]
Environment=RAILS_ENV=development
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/bundle exec rails resque:restart_workers[2]
User=deploy
WorkingDirectory=/opt/wonda/current
Environment=rvm_bin_path=/usr/local/rvm/bin
Environment=GEM_HOME=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1
Environment=SHELL=/bin/bash
Environment=IRBRC=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/.irbrc
Environment=MY_RUBY_HOME=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1
Environment=LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/rh/rh-php71/root/usr/lib64
Environment=PATH=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/opt/rh/rh-php71/root/usr/bin:/opt/rh/rh-php71/root/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/opt/puppetlabs/bin
Environment=GEM_PATH=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@global
Environment=DBUSER=wonda
Environment=DBPASS=***************

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I run it the system appears to attempt to start the workers, even gives me a pid, but does not show them running We have added logging to it but there is no output.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: There is *some* log output - from `systemd`. Unless your host system is *really* broken. Edit your question to show it. You can probably see them all with a simple `systemctl status the-name-of-my.service`.

Comment: There is some output, but it is just showing that they are starting, like I said it gives me a pid, but they are dead by the time I check it.

Comment: In future: it is polite to copy+paste some exact messages. Even if your interpretation is they didn't tell you anything. For example, the absence of a certain message might be a massive clue to someone more familiar with the logs.  Thanks for showing the exact service file that produced this result, that that helped me get a good understanding.

Comment: This site in particular is designed to host good archives for people with the same problem.  So it's intended to allow questions that err on the side of having more information than absolutely necessary.  If you *want* to edit the question afterwards to improve the quality of the archive, that's also absolutely allowed & encouraged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be using `rvm` but having to set a lot of things manually. [`rvm-exec`](https://rvm.io/set/do) seems designed for this purpose. If you could get `rvm-exec` to work in a terminal, that would give you less possible things to go wrong when you convert it to a service...

<inspects remaining things to go wrong>

`ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/bundle exec rails resque:restart_workers[2]`

So where does `resque:restart_workers` come from, hmm?

This sounds like the classic problem of using the wrong readiness protocol.  And then being surprised when `systemd` kills all your processes, because what it *thought* was your main process, just forked and then exited.

If possible, the command you run with systemd should *not* fork into a "background process".  E.g. you want a command that would run in the foreground if you ran it in a terminal.  That will work well with the implied default `[service]` type, `Type=simple`.  Although setting `Type=exec` can give better error reporting, and I don't know any reason not to prefer it :-).

If you cannot - or alternatively, you need to know accurately when your service is started, and it *correctly* implements the `Type=forking` readiness protocol, but nothing better than that - you could add `Type=forking`.

Comment: I had tried forking previously and it did not work. I just tried it again and it is now working, of course I have all those env variables now, I will need to slim that down to see what got it to work. thank you.